# Redrawing bounding box border after object rotation with Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric.js (version 1.7.19) to draw on a canvas. I have a 'rotate' button which rotates the active object 90 degrees. The rotation works fine, but the objects bounding box border doesn't change to reflect the rotated object, which other than looking strange means that I can't select the object properly.

[image]

Here is my rotate object function.

```
rotateItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const currentAngle = this.state.activeItem.item(0).get('angle');
  this.state.activeItem.item(0).setAngle(currentAngle + 90).setCoords();
  fabricCanvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to post a demo where the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I was added a new fabric.Group to the canvas and then rotating the first item inside of the group (hence the `.item(0)`) when what I really needed to do was rotate the entire group. Removing `.item(0)` fixed my issue.

```
rotateItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const currentAngle = this.state.activeItem.get('angle');
  this.state.activeItem.setAngle(currentAngle + 90).setCoords();
  fabricCanvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. Did you try this group.addWithUpdate()? This will force the group to take the bounding box of the children