# fabricjs Dynamically set boundingbox

Tags: javascript, rotation, fabricjs, polygon

I have a polygon (right angle triangle) inside a group. When I rotate the polygon by like 20 degrees the group's bounding box is not what I want. I want to remove the extra space on the right side (see attached

```js
const points = [
  {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 100,
    "y": 100
  },
  {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 100
  },
  {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  }
]
const poly  = new fabric.Polygon(points);
poly.set({
    originX: "center",
  originY: "center",
    top: 150,
  left: 150,
  fill: "green"
})


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

var group = new fabric.Group();

window.group = group;
window.poly = poly;

canvas.add(group);
group.addWithUpdate(poly);
canvas.setActiveObject(group);
canvas.renderAll();

function rotate() {
  const shape = group.item(0);
  shape.set({
    angle: shape.angle + 20
  });
  group.addWithUpdate();
  group.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

document.getElementById("rotate").addEventListener("click", rotate);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

<button id="rotate">rotate</button>
```

image). I understand why the space is there since that is the bounding box of the polygon.

Is there a way to trim the groups bounding box to fit exactly the visible space of the polygon?
Ideally, it would be nice if this was part of the fabricjs api. Otherwise, I don't mind calculating the visible bounding area of the polygon myself, but is it then possible to use that bounding box to dynamically set the group's boundingbox?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/garliu/tekugfhb/10/

[image]

Comment: Did you  look  at?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475351/redrawing-bounding-box-border-after-object-rotation-with-fabric-js

Comment: Yes, I did. That problem is similar but not the same as my problem. I think that problem can be resolve using group.addWithUpdate(); to force the group to take the children's bounding box. The problem I'm having is that this is a rotated polygon. If this was a rectangle then it would be fine. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this issue? I am facing the same issue with my group object. The bounding box get redrawn to rectangle after rotation with extra padding.